# Ignore folder in stable, but not in devel branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have the following folder structure for my project

```
src/
   test_unit/
   package1/
      test_unit/
   package2/
      test_unit
output/
```

In my devel branch all folders should be version controlled, but
the master/stable branch should ignore and not merge test_unit/ and output/ folder.

How can I achieve this? With .gitignore it won't work because .gitignore will be merged
between the branches.

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files:

- in `master/stable` branch, you could have `.gitattributes` referring to a custom merge driver which would effectively ignore the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` coming from test_unit folders.
- in `devel` branch, you could have `.gitattributes` referring to a custom merge driver for ignoring the `.gitignore` coming from `test_unit` folders from the `master` branch, and keeping their own version of `.gitattributes`.

That way, you can define `.gitignore` in `test_unit` folders in the `master` branch: they won't impact `devel` branch in case of merge.

Answer (score -1):

I know that you're new here—so am I—but your question would attract more answers if you formatted it. Perhaps a list showing folder structure, like this:

```
 - List item
 - List item
  - List item
 - List item
```

That would turn into:

- List item
- List item

  - List item
- List item