# Git workflow, differences between devel and production branches on ignoring files

Tags: git, branch, gitignore

Say you have a **develop** branch and a **master** branch (master corresponding to production). In the *develop* branch you might have a *test* folder, a *scripts* folder that you want to version control.

But every time you merge the *develop* branch with new changes to the *master* branch, you want to ignore *scripts* and *tests*, because *master* branch has exactly the same files that are in production (so that you could even automatically deploy the *master* branch in every merge).

What's the best way to achieve that? There should be a way to merge everything but some 'ignored' folders.

My question is a bit the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927339/ignore-folder-in-stable-but-not-in-devel-branch). But I am surprised that is a not very popular question. I think this is a problem every developer that wants to be able to deploy automatically and is testing code will have to face

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.gitattributes` file in master with

```
test merge=ours
scripts merge=ours
```

Note: I haven't actually been able to test this, because apparently `.gitattributes` with `merge=ours` [does not work on msysgit](http://www.mail-archive.com/git-users@googlegroups.com/msg04310.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (from my old answer) is to use [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768125/6309) declared in `.gitattributes` file.

[image: filter driver]

That would allow, on checkout, to *generate* the right script or config file, from the combination of template files and value files.

You would keep all value files (for master or dev) in the same directory: no need to merge them (they are different).
The common files are generated, so they are not versioned (not merged either)